# setting JDEE-server in emacs?

Tags: java

i've installed jdee from `package-list` it was elpa i think .. color highlight and indentation are working fine . but

when i run any command ( JDEE commands )  i get this message :

> Customize ‘jdee-server-dir’ to point to dir with JDEE jars. See
>   http://github.com/jdee-emacs/jdee-server

will i visited the link i don't know where to find the bundle files ?

Answer (score -1):

If you follow instructions for building jdee-server you will find the bundle files in 'target' directory. All the instructions are under the link.

Comment: Welcome to emacs SX!  Could you provide a bit more information, ie how/where is this 'target' directory defined?

Comment: What @JeanPierre said. And point to where to find the "instructions". Please make this answer more self-contained, so more useful.

Comment: @JeanPierre target directory is automatically added by maven, when you build the jar part of jdee, it's all explained in readme https://github.com/jdee-emacs/jdee-server